# How to hide/remove special characters in markdown files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my markdown files special characters appear when I type in markdown.

How do I hide it?

[image]

Help about:

```
Version: 1.86.2 (user setup)
Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
Date: 2024-02-13T19:40:56.878Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26908389
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by disabling the following settings for the extension Markdown-All-In-One

[image]

In VS Code settings under extension markdown disable the settings for

- Decoration:Render Hard Line Break
- Decoration: Render Link
- Decoration: Render Paragraph

Comment: Copy what in the image to the answer, [learn more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).